# Red5 - Linux Installation init.d script

Tags: installation, red5

I have followed this pretty little [tutorial](http://tumbledesign.com/how-to-install-red5-0-9-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/) to install red5 on Ubuntu 11.04
I can now run it from `/usr/share/red5/red5.sh`
But I'd like to have a init.d script like `/etc/init.d/red5 start|stop|restart|...`
I found one [here](http://www.linuxmaza.com/system-administration/init-script-to-start-stop-restart-red5-flash-media-server/) but when used, it's saying

> .: 11: Can't open /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

What can I do to make it work ?

**Edit**

Replacing `. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` by `. /lib/lsb/init-functions` will give me

> $ sudo /etc/init.d/red5 stop
>   /etc/init.d/red5: 50: status}”: not found
>   stop : missing task name
>   Try 'stop --help' for more information.
>   restart : missing task name
>   Try 'restart --help' for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The init script you've found depends on non-existing file. Try replacing:

```
# Source function library
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
```

with this:

```
# Source function library
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

It's possible that there will be more changes needed.

Comment: Apparently the script is much older and less incompatible then I thought. I recommend to look for other alternatives, e.g. [init.d script from BigBlueButton](http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/downloads/detail?name=red5-ubuntu) looks good - be sure to check variables in the script to see if they are relevant for your system.